Timepoint lsmeans post-hoc mean comparisons
Can anyone suggest which is the most appropriate test?
I have changes from baseline (4 timepoints including baseline) in the Y axis and the timepoints in the X axis, 4 treatments. I want to see, if there are significant differences across timepoints within treatment. Is an lsmeans test with Tukey adjustment appropriate?
